# Extract data from lines of a text file

Tags: python, string, file, split, extract

I need to extract data from lines of a text file. The data is name and scoring information formatted like this:

```
Shyvana - 12/4/5 - Loss - 2012-11-22
Fizz - 12/4/5 - Win - 2012-11-22
Miss Fortune - 12/4/3 - Win - 2012-11-22
```

This file is generated by another part of my little python program where I ask the user for the name, lookup the name they enter to ensure it's valid from a list of names, and then ask for kills, deaths, assists, and whether they won or lost. Then I ask for confirmation and write that data to the file on a new line, and append the date at the end like that. The code that prepares that data:

```
data = "%s - %s/%s/%s - %s - %s\n" % (
        champname, kills, deaths, assists, winloss, timestamp)
```

Basically I want to read that data back in another part of the program and display it to the user and do calculations with it like averages over time for a particular name.

I'm new to python and and I'm not very experienced with programming in general so most of the string splitting and formatting examples I find are just too cryptic for me to understand how to adapt to quite what I need here, could anyone help? I could format the written data differently so token finding would be simpler, but I want it to be simple directly in the file.

Comment: When you read it back, what data structure do you want to store it in?

Comment: oh goodness thank you all so much finally some of this splitting business makes sense! I'll give a few of these a try and see what works best for me, thank you! and happy thanksgiving!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following will read everything into a dictionary keyed by player name. The value associated with each player is itself a dictionary acting as a record with named fields associated with the items converted to a format suitable for further processing.

```
info = {}
with open('scoring_info.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        player, stats, outcome, date = (
            item.strip() for item in line.split('-', 3))
        stats = dict(zip(('kills', 'deaths', 'assists'),
                          map(int, stats.split('/'))))
        date = tuple(map(int, date.split('-')))
        info[player] = dict(zip(('stats', 'outcome', 'date'),
                                (stats, outcome, date)))

print('info:')
for player, record in info.items():
    print('  player %r:' % player)
    for field, value in record.items():
        print('    %s: %s' % (field, value))

# sample usage
player = 'Fizz'
print('\n%s had %s kills in the game' % (player, info[player]['stats']['kills']))
```

Output:

```
info:
  player 'Shyvana':
    date: (2012, 11, 22)
    outcome: Loss
    stats: {'assists': 5, 'kills': 12, 'deaths': 4}
  player 'Miss Fortune':
    date: (2012, 11, 22)
    outcome: Win
    stats: {'assists': 3, 'kills': 12, 'deaths': 4}
  player 'Fizz':
    date: (2012, 11, 22)
    outcome: Win
    stats: {'assists': 5, 'kills': 12, 'deaths': 4}

Fizz had 12 kills in the game
```

Alternatively, rather than holding most of the data in dictionaries, which can make nested-field access a little awkward — `info[player]['stats']['kills']` — you could instead use a little more advanced "generic" class to hold them, which will let you write `info2[player].stats.kills` instead.

To illustrate, here's almost the same thing using a class I've named `Struct` because it's somewhat like the C language's `struct` data type:

```
class Struct(object):
    """ Generic container object """
    def __init__(self, **kwds): # keyword args define attribute names and values
        self.__dict__.update(**kwds)

info2 = {}
with open('scoring_info.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        player, stats, outcome, date = (
            item.strip() for item in line.split('-', 3))
        stats = dict(zip(('kills', 'deaths', 'assists'),
                          map(int, stats.split('/'))))
        victory = (outcome.lower() == 'win') # change to boolean T/F
        date = dict(zip(('year','month','day'), map(int, date.split('-'))))
        info2[player] = Struct(champ_name=player, stats=Struct(**stats),
                               victory=victory, date=Struct(**date))
print('info2:')
for rec in info2.values():
    print('  player %r:' % rec.champ_name)
    print('    stats: kills=%s, deaths=%s, assists=%s' % (
          rec.stats.kills, rec.stats.deaths, rec.stats.assists))
    print('    victorious: %s' % rec.victory)
    print('    date: %d-%02d-%02d' % (rec.date.year, rec.date.month, rec.date.day))

# sample usage
player = 'Fizz'
print('\n%s had %s kills in the game' % (player, info2[player].stats.kills))
```

Output:

```
info2:
  player 'Shyvana':
    stats: kills=12, deaths=4, assists=5
    victorious: False
    date: 2012-11-22
  player 'Miss Fortune':
    stats: kills=12, deaths=4, assists=3
    victorious: True
    date: 2012-11-22
  player 'Fizz':
    stats: kills=12, deaths=4, assists=5
    victorious: True
    date: 2012-11-22

Fizz had 12 kills in the game
```

Comment: this seems promising, i have it working on my file, how can I get a specific stat out for a player? my tutorial book i'm following doesn't go very deep into dictionary syntax, how could I for example print "Fizz had ", kills, "in the game".

Comment: @Kassandra: That would be `print 'Fizz had %s kills in the game' % info['Fizz']['stats']['kills']`. There are other ways of structuring your data, for example by using one or more custom classes or perhaps by using a built-in class like `namedtuples` in the `collections` module. They would let you write `info['Fizz'].stats.kills`.

Comment: oh gosh that does sound nice, i'll try your bit here and see if i can get what i want out, i didn't know I could do it like that i've been trying to adapt a whole new function setup into my file to handle that, when i could just be setting some vars, ill give that a try, the notation on namedtuples looks nice too i'll try that as well, thank you again!

Comment: @Kassandra: I hesitated about whether to put the `Struct` idea in my updated answer or not because it might be too advanced for someone new to Python -- but the alternative would have been multiple custom classes and/or `namedtuples` -- a lot more code -- so I decided it would be worth the risk. The code for it is very short because classes are implemented internally using dictionaries.

Comment: i seem to be having some trouble integrating a new field into this dictionary. I need it to include a `gameid` key and get `00523` from the lines `[00523] Lulu - 6/1/19 - Win - 2012-11-23`, and i'm not sure if dictionaries allow it or if i would want it or not but i think i would want `stats` to be a sortof "subfolder" of `gameid`, so the dictionary would have a structure sortof like `champion > gameid > stats > kills, deaths, assists, result, date` i'm not sure if that can be done with this dictionary or not.

Comment: Since it seems likely you'd want to store information about than one game per player, you might want to consider putting several of them some kind of suitable container like a dictionary that was keyed by `gameid` to an associated a `stats` `Struct` composed of the items you're tracking for each game. This games dictionary of `stats` could then be made an attribute of the `champion` `Struct` designated `games` when it's created. i.e. `Struct(champ_name=player, games=games_dict, ...)`.

Comment: i'll see if i can manage that with adapting your above struct example, i've been trying to adapt the previous dictionary to do it but it's just not liking the combinations of strip and regex split, i might just reformat the data to use a simpler single delimiter, i'd probably be done with this whole thing by now if i had just used |'s or something, but that doesn't look so nice in the file; i suppose i could write an exporter that would reformat desired lines to generate a secondary, nicer looking file, or maybe i could keep 2 versions in the same file, separating the two blocks by some ***'s

Comment: You should look into using [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) for the data in your files. Python has very good support for both reading and writing this well-known format. Another possibility is to store the data in JSON or Python format. There's a bulit-in module for the former and you can design your own and just `import` or `execfile` the latter.

Comment: thats a good thing to consider, i do hope to be using sql or something eventually on another (much bigger) project anyways so it would be good to try something besides writing and reading strings to text files, i'll look into that and see if it looks simple enough to make this easier, i have seen posts about both of those all over here in my searches, as long as i could export a more formatted text file from that data (which would probably be much easier then this string parsing business since at that point it's just writing vars which i already have working perfectly), thanks :)

Comment: Yes, a full-fledged database might be appropriate for storing this data since it's hierarchical, which can be awkward with simple delimited-field files. Another viable alternative I forgot to mention was the built-in `shelve` module, which basically gives you persistent dictionaries and is very easy to use because it's so similar to one.

Comment: i'll take a look at shelve thanks i hadn't heard of it before

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to read the data out from your textfile example.

**First method**

You can use python's csv module and specify that your delimiter is `-`.

See http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/csv/

**Second method**

Alternatively, if you don't want to use this csv module, you can simply use the `split` method after you have read each line in your file as a string.

```
f = open('myTextFile.txt', "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    words = line.split("-")   # words is a list (of strings from a line), delimited by "-".
```

So in your example above, `champname` will actually be the first item in the `words` list, which is `words[0]`.

Comment: Didn't quite finish typing earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use split (' - ') to get the parts, then perhaps again to get the numbers:

```
for line in yourfile.readlines ():
    data = line.split (' - ')
    nums = [int (x) for x in data[1].split ('/')]
```

Should get you all the stuff you need in data[] and nums[]. Alternatively, you can use the re module and write a regular expression for it. This doesn't seem complex enough for that, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Iterates over the lines in the file.
for line in open('data_file.txt'):
    # Splits the line in four elements separated by dashes. Each element is then
    # unpacked to the correct variable name.
    champname, score, winloss, timestamp = line.split(' - ')

    # Since 'score' holds the string with the three values joined,
    # we need to split them again, this time using a slash as separator.
    # This results in a list of strings, so we apply the 'int' function
    # to each of them to convert to integer. This list of integers is
    # then unpacked into the kills, deaths and assists variables
    kills, deaths, assists = map(int, score.split('/'))

    # Now you are you free to use the variables read to whatever you want. Since
    # kills, deaths and assists are integers, you can sum, multiply and add
    # them easily.
```

Comment: I'm trying this out but i think I'm not using it right, I'm trying to do     'info = "Miss Fortune - 12/4/3 - Win - 2012-11-22"
for item in info:
 champname, score, winloss, timestamp = item.split(" - ")
print champname'

Comment: If you want to test with a single line, use `for line in ["Miss Fortune - 12/4/3 - Win - 2012-11-22"]:`, in a list and not the raw string. Otherwise it'll read the individual characters and try to extract the information from them.

Answer (score 1):

First, you break the line into data fragments

```
>>> name, score, result, date = "Fizz - 12/4/5 - Win - 2012-11-22".split(' - ')
>>> name
'Fizz'
>>> score
'12/4/5'
>>> result
'Win'
>>> date
'2012-11-22'
```

Second, parse your score

```
>>> k,d,a = map(int, score.split('/'))
>>> k,d,a
(12, 4, 5)
```

And finally, convert the date string into date object

```
>>> from datetime import datetime    
>>> datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%M-%d').date()
datetime.date(2012, 1, 22)
```

Now you have all your parts parsed and normalized to data types.