# Fetch data from another file

Tags: python

is it possible to get data from another file and compare it to my main input file and replace the string in it. I can't explain it clearly so I'll just show you.

Input:

```
Employee Number/Employee Name/Employee Extension
2022/Johnny Storm/188
2023/Reed Richards/189
2024/Sue Storm/190
2025/Ben Grimm/191
```

The log in my main input file only prints the Employee Number:

```
Employee Number, Time In
2022,07:27:01
2025,06:59:49
2023,06:40:31
2024,06:40:28
```

So what I'm trying to do is...

Pseudo code:

```
with open(emplst) as ulst:
  for line in ulst:
    EmpNum,EmpName,EmpExt = (item.strip() for item in line.split('/'))
    ulist[EmpNum] = dict(zip(('EmpNum'),(EmpName)))

if enum in EmpNum:
   replace enum with EmpNum + "," + EmpName + " Ext. " + EmpExt
```

Output:

```
2022,Johnny Storm Ext. 188,07:27:01
```

Note:
I am also seeking some info from this method but I keep failing in replacing the text: [Extract data from lines of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521397/extract-data-from-lines-of-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
with open(emplst) as ulst:
    for line in ulst:
    EmpNum,EmpName,EmpExt = (item.strip() for item in line.split('/'))
    ulist[EmpNum] = dict(zip(('EmpNum'),(EmpName)))
```

`ulst` is  not a dictionary that you can simply assign the value. It is a `file` object  and that too opened in readonly mode.

For this I would suggest you to
-->make a temporary file do `write` all the stuff you want to after modification

-->remove original file

--> and then rename temporary file to original file.

Somewhat like this:

```
with open(emplst) as ulst:
    with open("temp.txt", "w") as temp:
        for line in ulst:
            EmpNum,EmpName,EmpExt = (item.strip() for item in line.split('/'))
            if enum in EmpNum:
                temp.write(EmpNum + "," + EmpName + " Ext. " + EmpExt)
            else:
                temp.write(line) #dont touch it if record is not found
os.remove(emplst)
os.rename("temp.txt",emplst)
```